# space after 2 digits eg: 03 9876 6544

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want show mobile number in  this**(03 9876 6544)** way,i.e. space after two digit then after 6 digit in angularjs view.
I am getting this value from controller, in view {{obj.number}}.

Please tell me how to this.

Thanks

Comment: What did you do so far? Can you paste your code?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of regular expression, you can use the given below code to achieve desired result:

```
$scope.result = "0398766544".replace(/^(.{2})(.{4})(.*)$/, "$1 $2 $3");
```

[Additional information about this method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

---

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.result = "0398766544".replace(/^(.{2})(.{4})(.*)$/, "$1 $2 $3");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{result}}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks man,but in your example "03 9876 6544" is a string and already have space after 2nd digit and 6th digit, but i am getting integer like 0398766544 from api. pls help me in this case.

Comment: I already edited the demo, removed the spaces and it still works.

Comment: I had no idea about the use of special replacement patterns in .replace(). A brilliant method to do this.
Adding a link here to help others. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Comment: I added it to the answer, thanks for recognizing me. Always useful to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

If the value you get has no space and you want to create spaces, then create afunction like this:

```
function makeSpaces(nospaces) {
var first = nospaces.slice(0, 2);
var second = nospaces.slice(2, 6);
var third = nospaces.slice(6, 10);
var result = first + " " + second + " " + third;
return result;
}
```

and then: `makeSpaces("0398766544") = 03 9876 6544`

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

you can use substr() to format your phonenumber in javascript, and then bind it to HTML

```js
obj.number = '1234567890';
obj.number = obj.number.substr(0,2) + ' ' + obj.number.substr(2,4) + ' ' + obj.number.substr(6);
```